# Trouble facing creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: tables]

I have two tables `Product` and `OrderItem`, shown in the screen shot.

I want to create a stored procedure to update the `TotalSale` column of `Product` table with the amount of money collected from all the sales of that particular product.

To populate the `TotalSale` column, I have to calculate the total amount row by row multiple time for same product from `OrderItem` by multiplying `UnitPrice` and `Quantity` columns and then again have to add those multiple total amount per product to get the Total Sale per product. I am a beginner and having trouble figuring it out.

I added a column in `OrderItem`:

```
ALTER TABLE OrderItem 
    ADD TotalSale DECIMAL NULL

UPDATE dbo.OrderItem 
SET TotalSale = UnitPrice * Quantity
```

Then I calculated the sum of those multiple total amount per product to get the total sale per product:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(TotalSale) AS Gross 
FROM 
    OrderItem 
GROUP BY 
    ProductId
```

Now, as a beginner, I am not able to figure out how to populate that column with that calculated total values. Any hints or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please, provide the structures for the tables involved. Also, please provide a simple example that inserts the data you require and the results expected.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include that screenshot, however, please don't. When supplying details of a table provide it as DDL statements. If you're supplying data, then provide DML statements for those tables (the ones you provided DDL statements for). Images of data aren't helpful to those your asking help from; making your question far less likely to receive an answer. Also please do include the FULL SQL statement you tried to create the SP you need and explain why it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I am stuck at writing an insert statement: Insert into Product TotalSale ( select sum(UnitPrice*Quantity) from OrderItem group by ProductId)   Don't know how to write it. I know what I want to do but how to do is where I am getting stuck at.

Comment: "how to populate that column with that calculated totl values" storing calculated results in SQL tables normally goes against all normalisation "rules".. So could make a VIEW (where you calculate) and query the view instead.. Or use a CTE (WITH ... AS...) query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the problem is a little hard to understand at the beginning, I will try to help you, I believe that you can perfectly do:

```
  With MyCTE AS
    ( SELECT SUM(TSale) AS TotalSaleOI
       FROM OrderItem GROUP BY ProductId
    )
UPDATE P
SET TotalSale = C.TotalSaleOI
FROM Product AS P
INNER JOIN MyCTE AS C ON P.ProductId = C.ProductoId
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, I think the following query will work for you:

```
UPDATE Product
SET TotalSale = COALESCE(
    (SELECT SUM(TotalSale) 
    FROM OrderItem 
    WHERE OrderItem.ProductID = Product.ProductID), 0)
```

The ISNULL clause will ensure that if there are no orders for the product, it will calculate 0 as the result.

Comment: Use `COALESCE` (has the same structure as IFNULL) instead then you have cross database vendor support because COALESCE is ANSII SQL